# Mysql query check whether the user was assigned

Tags: mysql

I need a help in this query.

A user only sees a list with a list type of complex or simple and which are assigned to his Account and no other Account.

I have executed this query,

```
SELECT 
    `main`.*, `ac`.`account_id`
FROM
    `list` AS `main`
        LEFT JOIN
    `account` AS `ac` ON ac.list_id = main.id
WHERE
    (ac.`account_id` = '31')
        AND (`type` IN ('simple' , 'complete'))
```

but i need to check whether the list was assigned to any other account. If the list was associated to any other account id other than 31 then I should not show that list.

Comment: "If the list was associated to any other account id other than 31 then I should not show that list." - How is that decided? Can you provide some structure, relationships and data?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: list - id,name,code
account - id, list_id, account_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following condition to your WHERE clause:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM account ac
    WHERE ac.list_id = main.id
      AND ac.account_id <> 31
)
```

There are also other ways with `NOT IN (SELECT ..)` or with an excluding LEFT JOIN (antijoin).